# Returning customers / 2 conditions / 1id many rows

Tags: sql

I have a table with column manager_id (many IDs and many rows for the same id) and employee_id (many IDs, sometimes one employee works for many managers).

How could I return a list of manager_ids with employees both "X" and "Y"? I tried with HAVING X and Y, but it's not in the same row as 1manager_id has 1employee_id in one row so it's impossible. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use

Comment: Self join. Standard approach.

Comment: How is this table structured to allow for multiple (direct/non-hierarchy) managers for a single employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you should take a look at [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-groupconcat-function-in-mysql) (in case you're using MySQL):

> "GROUP_CONCAT is a function which concatenates/merges the data from
> multiple rows into one field. It is a GROUP BY function which returns
> a string if the group contains at least 1 non-null value, if it does
> not, it returns a Null value."

Here's the basic syntax (the linked website contains explanation for other possible keywords, such as DISTINCT and ORDER_BY, which might be useful for you): `GROUP_CONCAT(column[ SEPARATOR string])` - The separator part is optional (check the examples below) (default separator is ',').

There are equivalents for other databases:

PostgreSQL (ver. 9+) and SQL Server 2017+: `string_agg(column[, separator])`

Here's how your query might look like in MySQL:

```
SELECT id, manager_id, GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id) FROM manager_employees GROUP BY manager_id;
```

In case you want to use a separator other than the default

```
SELECT id, manager_id, GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id SEPARATOR ' - ') FROM manager_employees GROUP BY manager_id;
```

refs:

- https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php
- https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-groupconcat-function-in-mysql

Comment: Works, thank you!

Comment: No problem! If possible, could you please mark the answer as accepted? @Sql_beginner_europe